# Wildcard character in a SCCM task sequence like clause

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012-r2

This should be ridiculously easy to find. I'd like to set up a condition in SCCM for a few task steps based on variables I have defined. What is the correct wildcard character to use in the value here? I'm hoping to avoid needing to go the wmi search route since this will make it easier for others to maintain.

These are text based and I'm just wanting to parse it like the following.

```
 OSDComputerName like "Secure%Machine"
 OSDComputerName like "Secure*Machine"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct wild card character is the % sign. Here's some examples:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/f59d7bbd-b99a-4e8f-ac48-2bfdf0e7f098/sccm-queries-support-wildcard-or-not?forum=configmgrgeneral

http://eskonr.com/2012/06/sccm-collection-to-use-wildcard-in-string-matching/

Answer (score 2):

This actually depends on where you want to use the query.
If it is in a query for a collection % is correct.
The same is true if you want to use a wmi query within a TS step. Both of these fall back to WQL where % is the wildcard character.

However if you use a condition on a TS Variable (or collection variable) the correct wildcards are * and ?. This is undocumented but confirmed by the ConfigMGrTeam (see [here](https://configurationmanager.uservoice.com/forums/300492-ideas/suggestions/16620427-task-sequence-options-tab-task-sequence-variable), and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/SCCM/comments/6zg9az/why_is_there_a_like_condition_for_task_sequence/))